# Datamaps is giving me a Cannot read property 'albersUsa' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, import, datamaps

I'm getting this error when try to create a map:

[image: Datamaps error]
I'm currently using version `"datamaps": "^0.5.8",` this is directly from my `package.json`. I also checked the `package.json` in the actual package to see where main was pointing:

[image: Datamaps package.json <code>main</code> parameter]
I found a related issue, maybe even the same issue here:

https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/issues/259

Problem is that no one ever said what the answer was, one person mentioned that only a specific country js file was being loaded but I checked and `datamaps.all.js` is being loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is to be attributed to the new modularity of D3 v4, which made it necessary to [flatten namespaces](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-40):

> However, there is one unavoidable consequence of adopting ES6 modules: every symbol in D3 4.0 now shares a flat namespace rather than the nested one of D3 3.x.

For your code this means that some references using the d3-geo module are invalid because they refer to properties which are no longer available in v4:

> #### [Geographies (d3-geo)](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#geographies-d3-geo)
>
> - d3.geo.albersUsa ↦ [d3.geoAlbersUsa](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoAlbersUsa)

Because datamaps has defined a dependency on D3 like `^3.5.6` this will include D3 v4. However, because of the above mentioned changes in the namespace you will have to use a D3 **v3** instead.

Comment: Thanks, ya I ended up nuking my `node_modules` and reinstalling which then gave me the right dependencies

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks! Does it mean I won't be able to use D3 v4 when I use ES6 modules, or is there any other workaround or future solutions?

Comment: @crisscross Why shouldn't you be able to use v4 just because you are using modules in your code? The question here was about incompatibilities between versions due to the adoption of ES6 modules in D3 v4. I am afraid, I don't understand what you are after. There are many resources available on how to integrate ES6 with D3, e.g. https://learningd3.com/blog/using-es6-with-d3/.

Comment: @altocumulus I was not able to make it working for v4 and constantly ran into issue. With v3 it works right away. I guess I have to dive into these migration resources then. Thanks.